# error page handling not apper on asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

is there any problem with error page on browser ?, just when i hit  http://localhost:5000/invalid, the error info only appear on cli

this is my startup.cs files

```html
 
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole();

            env.EnvironmentName = EnvironmentName.Production;
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
          

            app.Use(async (context, next) => 
            {
                if(context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("invalid"))    
                    throw new Exception("ERROR!");
                
                await next();
            });

            app.UseFileServer();
            
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my .csproj file

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: What is the problem you're experiencing ?

Comment: an error handling page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling, it's just same when i already add diagnostic package